# Question of using pd.to_datetime to convert my csv time data to datetime64 format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv that contains time in one column, and the time continues to the next day for example from index 180 to index 187, time changes from 23:43 to 00:01. ( sorry about the inconsistent index because I eliminated some rows in csv.)

```
                               bus stop   time  distance_from_ previous_stop
0                           Masons Road  05:40                           0.0
1                    Morrell Avenue Top  05:49                           3.3
2                           County Hall  06:03                           2.0
3                           Elms Parade  06:11                           4.4
..                                  ...    ...                           ...
179                  Morrell Avenue Top  23:29                           3.3
180                         County Hall  23:43                           2.0
185                     Kenilworth Road  00:01                           4.3
187                     Dalton Barracks  00:13                           4.0
189     Abingdon, Stratton Way, stop A3  00:18                           3.5
```

But this change of time across 0:00 has caused the inconsistent of datetime when I used `pd.to_datetime(csv.time, format='%H:%M')`, which lead to a discontinuous plot of graph when I use plt.plot
[look at the discontinuous behavior of 'city 4' line when it comes at the end of the day (24:00)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoBol.png)

So I wonder how can I fix this problem. Is there anything I can do with 
`pd.to_datetime(csv.time, format='%H:%M')` to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: You have removed some rows as you said, which is causing discontinuous graph. Is there reason behind removing those rows ? NaN values, if yes please try to fill NaN values instead of removing rows.